# Rounded tag shape with CSS

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to create this shape with html/css:

[image]

My requirements are:

- body background might change per page, so cannot use alpha masking images
- the background color is transitionable on hover
- all corners of the shape are rounded

With sharp corners you could do it with css triangles, but the rounded ones give me trouble.

What I have so far in HTML:

```
<ul class="tags">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Longer text in tag</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```

In CSS:

```
.tags {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.tags li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
    position: relative;
}
.tags a {
    background: #283c50;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;

    -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: background 200ms ease;
    transition: background 200ms ease;
}
.tags a:before {
    background: #283c50;
    content: "";
    height: 1.75em;
    width: 1.75em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1em;
    right: -0.87em;
    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);

    -webkit-border-radius: 0.625em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.625em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.625em;
    -ms-border-radius: 0.625em;
    border-radius: 0.625em;

    -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: background 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: background 200ms ease;
    transition: background 200ms ease;
}
.tags a:hover,
.tags a:hover:before {
    background: #1eaa82;
}
```

It only looks ok on Chrome. For others, there are either differences in the triangle position or transition occurs at different times for the triangle and the actual tag. See example http://jsfiddle.net/hfjMk/1/

Is this even possible/feasible? Or do I have to discard the transition and use an image for the triangle part?

Comment: I don't really see much difference between Chrome and the others. Edit: Oh, Opera. Oh well.

Comment: I feel it's probably more hassle than it's worth to try and get this to actually look good in all browsers, mobile, etc. using pure CSS. I would maybe look at employing an image system which allows you to have auto-expanding tags which always look great.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a rotated pseudo element for this:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -41px;
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option at the moment is to use what you have, as this looks quite alright in most browsers. Furthermore I would suggest that you could use a browser sniffer (very dangerous) to fix text positioning in the buttons cross-browser.

there is the option of using an image ofcource, where basically the shape would be transparent instead of the background.

In that case you could change the background of an A tag as you wish, just set the image color to match the rest of the page layout.

This is the only thing I can think of right now, hope it's somewhat useful to you.